# Adding categorical columns into the prediction model

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, data-science

I got a dataframe of customers and information about their activity, and I've built a model that predicts if they buy the product or not. my label is a column 'did_buy' which assigns 1 if a customer bought, and 0 if not. my model takes into consideration the numeric columns, but I'd also like to add categorical columns into the predictive model and I'm not sure how to convert them and use them in my X train. here is a glimpse of my dataframe columns:

```
Company_Sector         Company_size  DMU_Final  Joining_Date  Country
Finance and Insurance       10        End User   2010-04-13   France
Public Administration       1         End User   2004-09-22   France
```

some more columns:

```
linkedin_shared_connections   online_activity  did_buy   Sale_Date
            11                        65           1      2016-05-23
            13                        100          1      2016-01-12
```

Comment: Are you not able to use the categorial variables for the model? What error are you getting? Scikit learn would automatically apply one hot encoding to the categorical variables.

Comment: Did you have a look at [pd.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)

Comment: I used the numeric variables such as 'online_activity' and 'linkedin_shared_connections' to predict the 'did-buy', and it was pretty good. but when I add for example a categorical column like 'company_Sector' I get the error message of 'can't convert string to float'.

Comment: another problem is converting the categorical DateStamp  'joining-date' column. I used this code:  data['joining_date'] =    pd.to_datetime(data['joining_date'])                   data['joining_date']=data['joining_date'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal)                     but it prints all the dates in 1970

Comment: @AshokKS No it wont. Scikit-learn will complain about not being able to convert strings to float. The user needs to do it himself.

Comment: Depending on the type of categorical data you may need to use different approaches available. You may one-hot encode them, or just encode them ordinally, or use some other technique. See [my answer here about some description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52948093/3374996).

Comment: Same about the time. You can extract day of month, month of year, week of month, year, etc as different features. And about "`data['joining_date']=data['joining_date'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal) but it prints all the dates in 1970`", this is not clear. You converted each date to number of days since 1970, so how can it print 1970? Can you post a reproducible example for that?

Answer (score 1):

you have different choices to convert categorical variables to numerical or binary variables.
for example, country column in your data frame has different values(e.g, France,China,,...). one of solutions that you can convert them to numerical variables is:
{France:1, China:2, ....}

```
#import libraries
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd
#Create a label encoder object and fit to Country Column
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(df['Country'])
# View the label {France,China,...}
list(label_encoder.classes_)
# Transform Country Column to Numerical Var
label_encoder.transform(df['Country']) 
# Convert some integers into their category names --->{China,China,France}
list(label_encoder.inverse_transform([2, 2, 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest that you first identify which categorical variables are ordinal (order counts ex. Good, Very Good, Bad etc) and which are nominal (order does not matter ex. color). For ordinal you could use map as follows:

```
    Category
0   Excellent
1   Excellent
2   Bad
3   Good
4   Bad
5   Very Good
6   Very Bad

df.Category = df.Categoy.map({'Excellent':5, 'Very Good':4, 
                              'Good':3, 'Fair':2, 'Bad':1, 'Very Bad':0})

    Category
0   5
1   5
2   1
3   3
4   1
5   4
6   0
```

For nominal variables you could implement the dummy variable method. Example:
Say your categorical variable has two values "Native" and "Foreign". You could create a column called "Native" that has 1 for Native and 0 for foreign. Could be implemented for multiple categories.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"Origin": ['Native', 'Native', 'Foreign', 'Native', 'Foreign']})

    Origin
0   Native
1   Native
2   Foreign
3   Native
4   Foreign

data['Native'] = pd.get_dummies(data['Origin'], drop_first=True)
data.drop("Origin", axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

This would result in:

```
    Native
0   1
1   1
2   0
3   1
4   0
```